# Do git tags persist after a branch is deleted?

Tags: git

If I have a tag on a specific commit that is part of a branch (no other branch has this commit), and I delete that branch, will the tag persist forever (as long as I don't delete the tag)?

```
*-*-*---* (master)
   \--x---* (foo)
```

A tag `foobar` points to the commit represented by the `x`.

I decide that branch `foo` is no longer supported/needed and I delete it.

But someone wants to checkout that specific tag because he depends on that specific version of my project.

Will the tag exist for him to `git clone --branch foobar`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. A tag is a name for a commit. Names keep commits alive and make them reachable. As long as you don’t delete the tag, the commit (and all commits preceding it in its history) will live forever. So a user of this repo can checkout the tag. As for your particular code, `git clone --branch foobar` will work with a tag; it will result in a detached head if foobar is not a branch, but that’s not a problem.